# Is there a way to display a message to the person who watch a video of my Cypress tests?

Tags: cypress

Logs are getting lost in the flux of commands. What is the best way to highlight the logs so that they stand out? I tried adding a div to the app and then removing it, but doing this causes focus to get lost during my tests. Is there a way to hide commands that are not logs in the left panel?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to overcome the problem of losing focus, there is a [.focus()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/focus) command that will reset the focused element after adding the `<div>`.

```js
cy.get('div.scan-actif input[name=testAlert]').focus()

cy.focused()
  .should('have.attr', 'name', 'testAlert')
```

Otherwise, you can remove commands (most of then) from the log by using `{log:false}` option.

```js
cy.wait(500, {log:false})
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to get the element, store it's ref and give him back focus once I am done. But it tells me this element doesn't exist anymore. I could use an id but I kind of hoped there would be something more out of the box in Cypress and that don't impact the test. Modifying the dom of my app for tests isn't a great solution...